# easy classes/objects creation with Perl?

Tags: perl, oop, cpan

I know it is possible to create classes/objects in Perl using the `bless` function and modules. Is there any CPAN module that would make this easier, preferably with automatic getter/setter generation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Moose](http://moose.perl.org) is a godsend. There are some notes in [Moose - a guide to the new revolution](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/61/Moose%20is%20Perl_%20A%20Guide%20to%20the%20New%20Revolution%20Presentation%201.pdf) by Ricardo Signes which are good, as well as the [manual](http://p3rl.org/Moose%3a%3aManual).

Comment: For a much lighter alternative to Moose, check out "Moo" - provides the "has" keyword and roles and that's about all. Start by reading bout / playing with Moose though.

Comment: [Mouse](https://metacpan.org/module/Mouse) is another lightweight alternative to Moose with very high compatibility, no dependencies and its very, very fast.